# Where to put floating action button when there are multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout with a MainActivity which incorporates a BottomNavigationBar and a FrameLayout for swapping out fragments. I want the BottomNavigationBar to stay fixed with every fragment having a fab which on the other hand disappears when scrolling. The problem is that I'm not sure which layout to use for the MainActivity and the Fragments and where to put the fab, I could put the fab either in the MainActivity's layout and change the behaviour of the fab for each fragments (don't know how though) or add a fab to every fragment's layout. When I do the latter I cannot reference the MainActivity's bottom bar to stay over it.

I tried #1:
MainActivity:

```
 <CoordinatorLayout>
 <FrameLayout/>
 <BottomNav/>
 <FAB/>
 </CoordinatorLayout>
```

And #2:

```
 <CoordinatorLayout>
 <FrameLayout/> -> fabs defined in each fragment layout
 <BottomNav/>
 </CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Main activites xml file looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And one of my fragments with FAB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".View.MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_item"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want the bottom nav and coordinator layout to be aware of the fab and the fab to be above the bottom nav without using hard-coded dp values but how do I do that?

Comment: If I were you I will put the fab inside the MainActivity and I'll just use ``fab.hide()`` to hide the fab

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CoordinatorLayout.Behavior logic, your fab should at the same level with CoorditorLayout.

For you i recommend this logic: Activity contains BottomNavigation, FrameLayout (fragment container). Then all your fragment contains:

```
 <CoordinatorLayout>
 <RecyclerView/>
 <FloatingButton/>
 </CoordinatorLayout>
```

It will give a power to construct UI of fragment exactly how you want.